# How to properly center the background image within the current bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm currently trying to get the entire background image to remain inside the user's window no matter what kind of device they are using. I have been able to add the background image but have not been successful in trying to implement the centering of the image. The current result is [image: this.]. (I'm still new to webdev, so don't worry about the navbar being there for now)

I've tried using a solution that I've seen some other projects use before to no avail:

```
html { 
  background: url(/images/login.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Since that solution took away the entire background image i got rid of it, now all i have is setting the background to the pic inside the main-content div.

```
<style>
    .main-content {
        background-image: url(/images/login.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

How do I properly go about fixing the background-size to fit the screen no matter the device?

Just in case anyone wanted to take a look Area/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml:
https://github.com/zhadjah9559/HelpDeskTicket/tree/4.MyTicketsView

Comment: Have you tried `background-position: center center` I know background images can take a bit of playing around with until you get it just right.

Also, if you post your HTML/CSS to Codepen, I'lll take a further deep dive into it. I just don't want to close your repo since its in C# and I don't have experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it fit the browser window with the below css style.

```
.main-content {
    background-image: url(/images/login.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

inside the css, you can try to adjust the width and height of the image to be 100%. Then add margin: auto to position the image to the center of the page.

```
<style>
    .main-content {
        background-image: url(/images/login.jpg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```